# Define a variable that chooses values -1 or 1

Tags: p5.js

In p5.js, I could define a variable as:

```javascript
var a = round(random(-1, 1))
```

And this will randomly output -1, 0, 1. Making it very likely to get 0. 
What would be a better way to define a variable that only output values -1 or 1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define your own random function

```
function getRandomNumber(){
  var a=random(-1,1);
  if(a>0)return 1;
  else return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an `if` statement. Something like this:

```
var a;

if(random() < .5){
  a = -1;
}
else{
  a = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer in one line.  I disagree with the accepted answer, you shouldn't define your own functions for something so simple.

```
var a = (random() < .5)?-1:1;
```